# Identity Owin - GenerateAsync

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, owin

Im using Identity method GenerateAsync for Token to confirm Email.

```
string confirmationToken = Uri.EscapeDataString (await userManager.UserTokenProvider.GenerateAsync("Login", userManager, user));
```

Using DataProtectorTokenProvide

```
UserTokenProvider = new DataProtectorTokenProvider<AppUser, int>(app.CreateDataProtector(new string[] { "Login,Contact, Marketing"}))
        {
            TokenLifespan = TimeSpan.FromHours(3)

        };
```

And i gent this token:

"w4tdigSgDmB70AS2%2FXu%2BT4rqpz75sej9bhvmirVyGzvzeBBsfFOFIiYrwN%2BJMPpEDhGL1ffqJG%2F%2BIsEN%2BXXqQi7MDs73oPq3EluEzHydc9dhuXANNnBJ1KvOFxJl6had24gyCgYMGmssLstJoGLE1Q%3D%3D"

But when i want valid this token i get 404 page. My page for valid not load nothing only 404.
When i filter %. from token my valid page is load.
I think **"%"** chars do something bad.

Do you know how i can encode this token or something?

Thanks

Comment: what's the full url? and do you have a controller that takes token?

Comment: url is something like website.com/Login/ID/TOKEN, Yes i have page for handle this token

Comment: so does the full URL you send out matches the controller/action?

Comment: yes, when i filter % chars its works fine, but with this encode isnt works

Comment: Add url encoding around generated token: http://tech.trailmax.info/2015/05/asp-net-identity-invalid-token-for-password-reset-or-email-confirmation/ - scroll to "Token changed in transit"